# Plus sign converts to &#x2B; in nopcommerce 41 but resolve into 42beta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.1

My website is build with `nopcommerce41`. '+' characters are being replaced with &#x2B on runtime.
Everything is working fine except for this issue.

Example: Google search results displays url look like `www.demo.com?search=+apple` but bing search engine display this same url look like `www.demo.com?search=&#x2B;apple`.

If user comes from bing search engine then user can't find expected result.
now I have compared the code of both versions of nopcommerce41 and nopcommerce42beta and result is as shown below:

```
view-source:http://nop42beta-001-site1.ftempurl.com/ (this site into 4.2beta)
e.g. <li class=facebook><a href=//www.facebook.com/+nopCommerce target=_blank>Facebook</a>

view-source:http://demo.nopcommerce.com/ (this site into 4.1)
e.g. <a href="https://plus.google.com/&#x2B;nopcommerce" target="_blank">Google+</a>
```

nopcommerce team already fixed this issue into nopcommrce 4.2beta but I dont want to upgrade my project. Can any one help me solve this issue?

This issue already reported into development section but this is a problematic bug so I have posted here.
https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/62489/plus-sign-converts-to-x2b-in-nopcommerce-versions-running-on-net-core.aspx

one example to understand this issue

```
one more example as below:-

In a Index.chtml file i have write code

@{ 
    Layout = null;
    var test1 = "/+apple";
}

<a href="/+apple">Sangeet1</a>
<a href="@test1">Sangeet2</a>



now i have run project then i got result as below

view-source:http://localhost:15543/


<a href="/+apple">Sangeet1</a>
<a href="/&#x2B;apple">Sangeet2</a>
```

second dynamic string + symbol convert into +(Unicode Hex Character Code) but first static value not converted.

Comment: Problem is solved. using HttpCompression(AddNopWebMarkupMin) problem is solved. this method compress the code also also prevent to convert to Unicode Hex Character Code.


 public class NopMvcStartup : INopStartup
{
            //add WebMarkupMin services to the services container
            services.AddNopWebMarkupMin();
}

above method need to include into NopMvcStartup to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

nocommerce is open source, you can find the changeset that fixes your issue and build a 4.1 version with this specific fix

Comment: i already checked all commit of nopcommerce 4.2beta but i didnt find changes related to this issue.